# Does Python cache the for loop iterable?

Tags: python, for-loop, caching

I was wondering about how the iterable is handled by the `for` loop in Python. For a fixed iterable that exists in memory, Python simply iterates over it with a loop, like:

```py
x=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in x:
    print(i)
```

But say we generate the iterable using a function, like:

```py
for i in sorted(x):
    print(i)
```

In this case, is the iterable computed the first time and then cached for subsequent iterations? Or is it re-computed every iteration?

Granted, the latter seems really really inefficient and so it's probably implemented in the former way. However, I wasn't able to find any documentation to support this claim, so if anyone could share that, it would be amazing!

Comment: Since you realize that it would be "really really inefficient", how about running an experiment? Won't replace documentation, but still...

Comment: Or even put a side effect in the computation, like printing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try the following code:

```
x = [1 for _ in range(10)]
for i in range(len(x)):
 print(x)
 x = [5]
```

as you can see, the output is:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[5]
[5]
[5]
[5]
[5]
[5]
[5]
[5]
[5]
```

which means, `range(len(x))` is computed only once, and it is being cached, not computed every time.
hoped that helped

Comment: not cached, but  it provides a generator object, which is then computed on

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in sorted(x):
    print(i)
```

Is the same as:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = sorted(x)
for i in y:
    print(i)
```

`sorted(x)` is only computed once, not for each iteration of the for loop. The function returns an array, which is then iterated by the for loop.